# Launch 2 vertical panes in terminal using TMUX

Tags: tmux

I want to start 2 panes side-by-side in a terminal window using tmux:

```
tmux \ 
  --vertical-pane='tsc -w' \
  --vertical-pane='nodemon --watch' \
```

It is extrememly difficult to figure out how to do this with the documentation, although I think it's quite possible to do.

I want to create a pane, and then tell the pane which command to run.

https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just missing `splitw` or `split-window`:

```sh
uuid="$(uuidgen)"
tmux new -d -s "$uuid"
tmux splitw -h -t "${uuid}:0.0"
tmux send-keys -t "${uuid}.0" "tsc -w" ENTER
tmux send-keys -t "${uuid}.1" "nodemon" ENTER
tmux a -t "$uuid"
```

[Here's the tmux man page on `splitw`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html):

> ```
>  split-window [-bdfhIvP] [-c start-directory] [-e environment] [-l size]
>          [-t target-pane] [shell-command] [-F format]
>                (alias: splitw)
>          Create a new pane by splitting target-pane: -h does a horizon‐
>          tal split and -v a vertical split; if neither is specified, -v
>          is assumed.  The -l option specifies the size of the new pane
>          in lines (for vertical split) or in columns (for horizontal
>          split); size may be followed by ‘%’ to specify a percentage of
>          the available space.  The -b option causes the new pane to be
>          created to the left of or above target-pane.  The -f option
>          creates a new pane spanning the full window height (with -h) or
>          full window width (with -v), instead of splitting the active
>          pane.
>
>         An empty shell-command ('') will create a pane with no command
>          running in it.  Output can be sent to such a pane with the
>          display-message command.  The -I flag (if shell-command is not
>          specified or empty) will create an empty pane and forward any
>          output from stdin to it.  For example:
>
>               $ make 2>&1|tmux splitw -dI &
>
>         All other options have the same meaning as for the new-window
>          command.
> ```

Comment: thanks, I can make my terminal have 3 windows, but they aren't evenly spaced into 3rds. I can manually evenly space them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>space</kbd> but do you know how to send those keys to the session programmatically?

Comment: Also, why the two 0s after this `tmux splitw -h -t "${uuid}:0.0"`? why not `tmux splitw -h -t "${uuid}:0"`

Comment: If you have multiple windows in one tmux session, you specify by `window.pane` (which would be `0.0` in this instance). If you only have one window, or want to use the current window, then just `.pane` is sufficient.

Comment: `splitw -h -l 33%` (according to the current man page) or `splitw -h -p 33` (according to the version I have installed) will make a 1:2 split. Then you can target your 0th pane again and `splitw -h -p 50` or `splitw -h -l 50%` (depending on version). That should give you 3 panes of roughly equal size (there were off by a column or two when I tried it on my machine).